# How to group results based on code type and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, sql-server-2016

| code | date |
| --- | --- |
| AB123456 | 2023-01-05 |
| AC555555 | 2023-02-02 |
| BB565656 | 2023-02-05 |
| DF123456 | 2023-01-08 |
| DD555555 | 2023-01-25 |
| EF565656 | 2023-01-15 |
| DD555577 | 2023-02-25 |
| EF565658 | 2023-02-15 |
| AG897456 | 2023-02-08 |

There are two types of code: "simple" and "express".
Codes begined with AB, AC or BB are "simple". Codes begined with "DF", "DD", "AG" or "EF" are "express".

I need a query that group by type (found by the first two letters of the code) and month-year (format "mm-yyyy").

The desired result is:

| **Type** | **Month** | **Quantity** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EXPRESS | 01-2023 | 3 |
| SIMPLE | 01-2023 | 1 |
| EXPRESS | 02-2023 | 3 |
| SIMPLE | 02-2023 | 2 |

How can I do this?

I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you up and running.

**code column transformation**

Leverage `LEFT` function to extract first 2 characters of the code column. Wrap it up in a `CASE` statement to decide whether it's SIMPLE or EXPRESS.

**date column transformation**

You could use 126 style for converting the date in combination with `varchar(7)` to get `YYYY-MM` style of your date

**grouping**

Use these transformations in `GROUP BY` to obtain groups of data and use `count(*)` to show quantity

```
select 
  case when left(code, 2) in ('AB','AC','BB') then 'SIMPLE'
       when left(code, 2) in ('DF', 'DD', 'A', 'EF') then 'EXPRESS'
       else 'UNKNOWN'
       end as type_format,
  convert(varchar(7), date, 126) as month_format,
  count(*) as quantity
from yourtable
group by
  case when left(code, 2) in ('AB','AC','BB') then 'SIMPLE'
       when left(code, 2) in ('DF', 'DD', 'A', 'EF') then 'EXPRESS'
       else 'UNKNOWN'
       end,
  convert(varchar(7), date, 126)
```

Comment: This is just an example, not tested, but should work from the top of my memory. Please check this yourself. There are also many different ways to perform these transformations.

Answer (score 0):

For get Month and Year Has a lot of ways,I used FORMAT

```
select s.Type,s.Month_,count(*) as Quantity
from (
        select *,case when code like 'AB%' or  code like 'AC%' or  code like 'BB%' then 'simple'  
                      when code like 'DF%' or  code like 'DD%' or  code like 'AG%' or  code like 'EF%' then 'express'
                      end as Type
                , FORMAT(date_,'MM-yyyy') as Month_

        from fa
)s
group by s.Type,s.Month_
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ze7NbgbG)